# Side-loaded Face-Unlock not working

Tags: face-unlock, side-loading

I downloaded and installed facelock.apk on my Motorola Android tablet (running 4.0.3) but it fails with "Face unlock couldn't start.".

What's the reason? What can I do to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

See [Goo.im](http://goo.im/gapps/). They have a collection of Google Apps as installable .zip files.

There is an explanation for which packages belongs to what Android version on top.

However there's currently only one separate package for Facelock.

Comment: thanks for your attention.
I installed it, but it is setup locker using face.
I wanna screen locker using face.

Answer (score 1):

The Facelock.apk may not be compatible or rather, clearly, missing some dependency with the Motorola's version of the framework.

It could well be modified to exclude the facelock application as well. To each and their own, each manufacturer are free to modify, add, subtract from the Google Android source to suit themselves.

It might help to obtain the `logcat` using the application [aLogcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat) (found on Google Play Store) and run that in the background and capture the output from the `logcat` whilst running facelock to see what is the underlying reason for the point of failure.